# How can I used Dismissible() when the child have BorderRadius()?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to use `Dismissible` in a `Container` with `BorderRadius` but the `onDismissed` Animation don't work properly, because the back ground don't have the same shape.

[image: This is a screen shot of the problem.]

I have tried this:

```
 Stack(
     overflow: Overflow.clip,
     children: <Widget>[
         MyBackgroundWidget(), // instead of background
         Dismissible(
             child: MyForegroundWidget(),
             // no background
         )
     ],
 );
```

[image: and that works if you don't have padding. But don't work in my case, because i have padding in my container. So it will look like this when onDismissed, before the animation its completely done.]

Comment: This really bothers me, I still haven't found a solution for it

Comment: did anyone figure this out? So many Flutter questions on here have no replies, years later...

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet how you've defined the `Dismissible`.?

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the dismissible widget under ClipRRect and add border radius to only CLipRRect and not the child widgets. That should fix your problem.

This question has already been discussed in:
[How to fix this dismissible widget border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57542470/how-to-fix-this-dismissible-widget-border/64417315)

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use a container behind the Widget

```dart
Container(
    color : Colors.blue,
    child : YourDismissible(),
)
```